# How to pass data from a 2nd VC to a VC inside a container in 1st VC in swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

I navigated to a VC (lets call is VC A) from a presented VC. In VC A, I have a container view and it has a VC (lets call is VC B).  From VC B I presented another VC (lets call is VC C). From VC C I need to pass a few data back to VC B. How can I achieve the same.

I tried using protocol, but protocol is not hitting my VC B.Its hitting VC A only. But since I'm presenting VC C from VC B, I can't connect the delegate to self from VC A. So it's not working.

Again tried to save the data a global variable. And I tried to set the value to fields in viewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear in VC B.But due to some reason it's crashing every time. The crash is getting on the line

```
containerView.addSubview(remitController.view).


        let remitController = remitStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddBeneficiaryController") as! AddBeneficiaryController
        addChildViewController(remitController)
        remitController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(remitController.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            remitController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            remitController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            remitController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            remitController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        remitController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: In this case is VC B the self and VC C the remitLauncher?

Comment: @AlanS,No..No need to check else case.. I updated the code.VC C is another Presented VC from VC B.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`closure`** to solve the problem statement.

Create a `closure` in `VCC` controller,

```
class VCC: UIViewController {
    var handler: ((String)->())?

    func passDataToVCB() {
        handler?("This is sample data.")
    }
}
```

Call the `handler` whenever you want to pass data back to `VCB` along with the relevant data. I used `String` here.

Next, in `VCB` when you're presenting instance of `VCC`, set the `handler` value,

```
if let vcc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCC") as? VCC {
    vcc.handler = {(value) in
        print(value)
    }

    //present vcc here...
    self.present(vcc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Im adding VC B in VC A. Container is actually in VC A. But presenting VC C is from VC B, which is added in container in VC A.

Comment: Yes. It'll work for that too. You just need to connect them using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this problem when i tried using a container view for two view controllers depending on a flag. The solution i came up with was using delegates. I suggest you create a delegate to be implemented by VC B. At the point of instantiation of VC C you set the delegate. It should be declared as weak in VC C to avoid a retain cycle and memory leak. Call the delegate and send back your data from VC C back to B

```
protocol CtoBDelegate : class{
     func sendMyDataBack()//pass in any arguments also
}
class VC_C : UIViewController{
      weak var delegate : CtoBDelegate?
      override func viewDidLoad(){
      //do something
      delegate?.sendMyDataBack
   }
 }

 class VC_B : UIViewController{
      override func viewDidLoad(){
         let vc_C = //instantiate your view controller
         vc_C.delegate = self
         present(vc_C, animated : true)
    }
}

extension class VC_B : CtoBDelegate{
       func sendMyDataBack(){
          //do something with received data in VC_B

       }
   }
```

Another crude way you could implement a communication is using NotificationsCenter. Simply register your notifications in VC_B and set up a method to be called when a notification is received. Then post a notification from VC_C passing along whatever you need with the userinfo of the notification. If you opt for this do remember to remove the notification observer from VC_B when you are done to avoid a leak.